# Payment Gateway does not provide test credit cards for developers

Tags: payment-gateway, credit-card, payment

I find myself working with a Payment Gateway that in their test environment  does not provide any possibility to test transaction using fictitious credit cards numbers. Actually they say that not only I will have to use a real credit card number but also that funds will be transferred and I would need to issue a refund request every time I test a transaction. This is a first time for me, different payment gateways have always provided a test environment that accepted a certain range of test credit cards and no actual funds were ever transferred in test mode.

I've not developed with too many Payment Gateways but the fact that they not provide with a "test environment" where transactions are just "tests" leaves me quite baffled.

I would appreciate some advice, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps have your client give you some pre-paid cards?  They're getting the money back anyways.

Comment: It turned out that they do provide a test credit card although they said they didn't initially. I will keep in mind pre-paid cards option for future. Thanks, Giuseppe